# NIFI - EvaluateXPath to use as attribute

Tags: function, text, extract, apache-nifi

I have an xml that I need to extract the value of `chNFe`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"
         xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         versao="4.00">
   <NFe>
   </NFe>
   <protNFe versao="4.00">
      <infProt Id="ID141220260216089">
         <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
         <verAplic>PR-v4_7_79</verAplic>
         <chNFe>00000000</chNFe>              <---------------- this value 
         <dhRecbto>2022-10-31T08:58:01-03:00</dhRecbto>
         <nProt>141220260216089</nProt>
         <digVal>kkKWL87hgKqmXQ7jL0qbQ2dgL3U=</digVal>
         <cStat>100</cStat>
         <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>
      </infProt>
   </protNFe>
</nfeProc>
```

I need to create an attribute with `evaluateXPath` processor to extract this `chNFe` as text.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `EvaluateXPath` processor:

- `Destination`: `flowfile-attribute`
- `Return Type`: `auto-detect`
- `Allow DTD`: `false`
- `chNFe` (dynamic): `/*:nfeProc/*:protNFe/*:infProt/*:chNFe/text()`